# Component not rendering Angular 2 Typescript

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm trying to learn Angular 2, after a lot of error messages i finally got the routes working and i can display the component i want. Now i want to show my homepage component, and i want this component to have a navbar component in it.

Home.ts:

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {Navbar} from './navbar/navbar'

@Component({
  selector: 'home'
})

@View({
  templateUrl: '/app/home/home.html'
})

export class Home {

    constructor:(public navbar: Navbar) {
    }

}
```

home.html:

```
<p>NICE!</p>
<navbar></navbar>
```

navbar.ts:

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'navbar'
})

@View({
  template: `
  <ul>
    <li>This is the navbar</li>
  </ul>
  `
})

export class Navbar{
}
```

The homepage is displaying, but the tag just stays `<navbar></navbar>` when i inspect it. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want the `navbar` component, you need to add it in the `directives` attribute of the parent component, not in its constructor, like so:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: '/app/home/home.html',
  directives: [ Navbar ]
})
export class Home {
  constructor() {

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed the answer for this question, but i'm afraid this throws me into the next error :(. Now my router is giving troubles again.

Comment: It seems my navbar didn't compile, compiled it again and works like a charm now! Thanks!